# How could I replace a number in a file via Linux script?

Tags: linux

Below string is in a file, and I need to replace the version number 31.1.4 with like 31.1.5 under Linux. I know sed should be used, but how?

```
my-version = "31.1.4";
```

I need to search "my-version = " and then replace the latter number with new number. I do not prefer to just replace the number, because then I have to check the number in the file first.

Another case is to replace below 31.1.4 to be 31.1.5.

```
#define MY_VERSION "31.1.4"
```

Comment: Read documentation of [sed(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html)

Comment: show your minimal effort

Comment: I checked the link you provide, but that case do not have "". My case is more complex. Have you tried?

Comment: The documentation refers to general [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)s. You can find books on them (and even books on `sed` ...) You should also read about [unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell)s and how to use [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) with them.

Comment: You might also use [gawk(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gawk.1.html), notably if you need arithmetic. And you could use Python, Perl, Guile, ... for your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `awk` solution like you requested in the comments:

```
$ cat file
my-version = "31.1.4";
my-version = "31.1.4";
somevar = 33;
my-version = "31.1.4";
$ awk -i inplace -F"=" '/my-version/ { gsub($2, " \"31.1.5\";"); }1' file
$ cat file
my-version = "31.1.5";
my-version = "31.1.5";
somevar = 33;
my-version = "31.1.5";
$
```

Comment: @Basile, yes. OP requested a modified answer for the first answer - that he&#39;d like to search for my-version=... :-)

Answer (score 2):

`sed "s/31\.1\.4/31\.1\.5/g"` for stream editing

`sed -i "s/31\.1\.4/31\.1\.5/g" file.txt` for inplace replacement in file.txt

Please note, here `.` escaped to `\.`, as `.` will match to "any character"

Comment: The dot is not understood verbatim. It has special meaning in regexps. You should backquote it. A line containing `31x1y4` is matching the  `sed s/31.1.4/31.1.5/g`

Comment: Thank you, I fixed answer. But not escaped version can work too, it very rare cases what can produce errors

Comment: Without escapes the commands are wrong (have a different behavior)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I need to search "my-version = " and then replace the latter number with new number. I do not prefer to just replace the number, because then I have to check the number in the file first.

Comment: Yes, but in practice for long string like 31.1.4 not other matches like 31a1b4.